# How to make spread operator enumerate through non-function properties only?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, spread-syntax, typescript-decorator

Stack: ReactJS 16.x, Typescript 2.8.1, create-react-app project.

I am getting a type error when using the spread operator to pass `props` from a TypeScript class to a React component.

The error occurs only when the class has a function defined. If the class has a function expression variable, the spread operator works fine. I believe it has to do with the enumeration of properties on the class. So, I use a decorator to mark the function as non-enumerable but am still getting the same error. Below is the code:

`Message` is the class I am trying to spread into a React Component.

```
export class Message {
  constructor() {
    this.init2 = (msg: string) => {
      this.msg = 'init2';
      return this;
    }
  }

  public msg: string;

  // This works with spread operator
  public init2: (msg: string) => Message;

  // This will cause the spread operator to fail
  public init(msg: string): Message {
    this.msg = msg;
    return this;
  }

  // Even with decorator to turn off enumeration, spread operator fails
  @enumerable(false)
  public initNoEnum(msg: string): Message {
      this.msg = msg;
      return this;
  }
}
```

ReactJS component who's prop is defined as `Message`:

```
export class MessageComponent extends React.Component<Message, any>{
  render() {
    return (<div>{this.props.msg}</div>);
  }
}
```

Render method which uses `MessageComponent`:

```
  public render() {
    const msg = new Message().init('hello world!');
    return <MessageComponent {...msg} /> // The spread here fails
  }
```

The `enumerable` decorator function:

```
  export function enumerable(value: boolean): any {
      return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
      descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
  }
```

**tsconfig:**

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./build",
  "module": "esnext",
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
  "sourceMap": true,
  "allowJs": true,
  "jsx": "react",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "rootDir": "src",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noImplicitThis": true,
  "noImplicitAny": true,
  "strictNullChecks": true,
  "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
  "noUnusedLocals": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true
},
```

If I comment out `init` and `initNoEnum` and keep `init2`, the spread operator works. With `init` and `initNoEnum`, the spread operator fails with similar message:

> Type '{ msg: string; init2: (msg: string) => Message; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNod...'.   Type '{ msg: string; init2: (msg: string) => Message; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'. Property 'init' is missing in type '{ msg: string; init2: (msg: string) => Message; }'.

What am I doing wrong? How do I make the spread operator only enumerate through properties and not functions?

Comment: You can't, function are properties and as such will always be spread by the spread operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why use a decorator when you could just remove the functions yourself

You can't use the spread operator to get only the non-function properties by default because functions are properties but perhaps with your `tsconfig` magic it should work, however, you can modify the object being passed to the spread operator first instead.

To use spread syntax to get only non-function properties without the `tsconfig` magic, I would suggest using a function to filter out the function properties and then use the spread operator like so:

```
const filterOutFunctions = object => {
  return Object.keys(object)
    .filter(key => typeof(object[key]) !== 'function')
    .reduce((filteredObj, currentItem) => {
      filteredObj[currentItem] = object[currentItem]
      return filteredObj
    }, {})
}

const objectWithFunctions = {
  aFunction() {},
  aProperty: 'A good ol string'
}

// Now you can do spread operator stuff with a filtered version like so:
{...filterOutFunctions(objectWithFunctions)}
// returns: { aProperty: 'A good ol string' }
```

The way this works is by iterating over the `keys` of `object` with `.filter` to filter out the keys that point to a function. Then we collect all of the remaining properties via assigning them to a new, empty, object with `.reduce`.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something different but this works.